# HTML and CSS: How to play video on website

Tags: html, css, video

I have this website where I post projects and articles, just for fun. I was wondering how I could post videos. I know you can easily put YouTube videos on your website but I don't want to be known as a YouTube. What are the different methods of implementing videos on my site that doesn't require users to download flash player etc. Thanks - Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple html5 video tag

> ```
> <!-- Simple video example -->
>  <video src="videofile.webm" autoplay poster="posterimage.jpg">
>      Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
>      but don't worry, you can <a href="videofile.webm">download it</a>
>        and watch it with your favorite video player!
> </video>
> ```

see mdn for more https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

```
<video width="480" controls poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif" >
   <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [videojs](http://videojs.com/). You can use the standard html5 video tag, but it also allows you to plug in a youtube url without worrying about embedding it. Plus I believe it gives you some css right out of the box. Pretty easy to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

To convert videos into MP4,WEBM and OGV formats you could use something like www.converterpoint.com